# Woocommerce order complete secondary email retrieved from account meta data key value

Tags: hook-woocommerce

Scenario: A customer buys any product and upon order completion an additional email gets sent to a stored value in the users meta data.

My meta field is stored in the database as follows:
Table: wp_usermeta
 
Column: meta_key = iconic-register-email
Column: meta_value = X

I need to retrieve the meta_value based on the meta_key Column iconic-register-email.

My code thus far:
(To be placed in the function.php file of the child theme)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'new_order_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function new_order_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

// Get the order ID (retro compatible)
$order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;

// Get the custom field value (with the right $order_id)
$my_field_name = get_post_meta($order_id, 'my_field_name', true);

if ($my_field_name == "empolyee1@company.com")
$recipient .= ', empolyee1@company.com';
elseif ($my_field_name == "empolyee2@company.com")
$recipient .= ', empolyee2@company.com';
return $recipient;
}
```

I am not getting any errors but I am also not getting any emails. I tried replacing

```
    $my_field_name = get_post_meta($order_id, 'my_field_name', true);
```

with

```
    $my_field_name = get_post_meta($order_id, 'iconic-register-email', true);
```

but that did not work.

In an effort to minimize static coding of each email address to be matched in code below:

```
    if ($my_field_name == "empolyee1@company.com")
```

is there a way to call the $recipient based off of the meta_value = X

Comment: If you stored this in the _user_ meta data table, then why are you using the _order_ id to try and fetch it? That surely should be the user id?

Comment: I see your point. I am not that well versed in PHP  I will try and replace all order id to user id and see if that helps. Thanks.